# Python process list based on a condition

Tags: python, list, split

I have list with some values

```
mylist = ['1', 'Tom', 'Jerry', '2', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']
```

My expected output

```
[{'id': '1', 'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry']}, {'id': '2', 'mod': ['Sinchan', 'Shero']}]
```

My Try outs

```
mylist = ['1', 'Tom', 'Jerry', '2', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']

data_list = []
mod = []
for i in mylist:
    if i.isdigit() == True:
        data = {}
        data['id'] = i
        data_list.append(data)
    else:
        mod.append(i)
        data['mod'] = mod
print data_list
```

Getting Output

```
[{'id': '1', 'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']}, {'id': '2', 'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']}]
```

Im trying to get the **mod** value based on the number and so on,I tried but stuck up with the logic, Please help me to get solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate mistake is to not create a *new* `mod` list for each user you found. Your dictionary entries all share a single list object, and appending more values to the list will show those extra entries through the shared references:

```
>>> mod = []
>>> data_list = [{'mod': mod}, {'mod': mod}]  # simplified version of your result
>>> data_list
[{'mod': []}, {'mod': []}]
>>> mod.append('Tom')
>>> data_list
[{'mod': ['Tom']}, {'mod': ['Tom']}]
>>> mod.append('Jerry')
>>> data_list
[{'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry']}, {'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry']}]
```

Remember: [Python names are references to values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), and you can share those references.

Instead, add a new, empty list to the `data` dictionary when you create it:

```
for i in mylist:
    if i.isdigit():
        data = {'id': i, 'mod': []}
        data_list.append(data)
    else:
        data['mod'].append(i)
```

With a new empty list attached to each `data` dictionary, you'll no longer see shared data:

```
>>> mylist = ['1', 'Tom', 'Jerry', '2', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']
>>> data_list = []
>>> for i in mylist:
...     if i.isdigit():
...         data = {'id': i, 'mod': []}
...         data_list.append(data)
...     else:
...         data['mod'].append(i)
...
>>> data_list
[{'id': '1', 'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry']}, {'id': '2', 'mod': ['Sinchan', 'Shero']}]
```

Note that you don't need to use `== True`; the `if` statement *already* tests if the expression produced a true value, `== True` to produce a `True` result is redundant here.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Pieters , I took your solution, this works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
In [33]: data = ['1', 'Tom', 'Jerry', '2', 'Sinchan', 'Shero']

In [39]: {k: [y[1] for y in x][1:] for k, x in itertools.groupby(zip(itertools.accumulate(map(int, map(str.isdigit, data))), data), lambda v: v[0])}
Out[39]: {1: ['Tom', 'Jerry'], 2: ['Sinchan', 'Shero']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create clear `mod` variable for each data:

```
  if i.isdigit() == True:
        data = {}
        data['id'] = i
        data_list.append(data)
        mod = []
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is you don't clear `mod` each time you reach a new digit.

Here's an alternative solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

g = [list(j) for _, j in groupby(mylist, key=str.isdigit)]
res = [{'id': num[0], 'mod': names} for num, names in zip(g[::2], g[1::2])]
```

Result:

```
[{'id': '1', 'mod': ['Tom', 'Jerry']},
 {'id': '2', 'mod': ['Sinchan', 'Shero']}]
```